# how do i make my tictactoe game a tie?

Tags: java, javafx, game-physics, tic-tac-toe

so I have a fully operable tic tac toe game but if no one wins the game just stops because I haven't introduced a tie measurement or object. so I decided to add an else after my if(hasWinner):

```
        public class TicTacToePractice extends Application{
        Pane gameboard = new Pane();
        Label displayPlayer = new Label("Player A");
        char winningChar = '?';
        boolean hasWinner = false;
        boolean isPlayerA = true;
        Button[] btnPosition = new Button[16];

@Override
public void start(Stage stage){
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    btnPosition[i] = new Button();
    btnPosition[i].setLayoutX(i % 4 * 100);
    btnPosition[i].setLayoutY(i / 4 * 100);
    btnPosition[i].setPrefSize(100, 100);
    final int pos = i;
    btnPosition[i].setOnAction(e->{setClick(pos);});
    gameboard.getChildren().add(btnPosition[i]);
    }
    displayPlayer.setLayoutX(170);
    displayPlayer.setLayoutY(420);
    gameboard.getChildren().add(displayPlayer);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gameboard, 400, 450);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public void setClick(int i){
   btnPosition[i].setFont(Font.font(30));
   if(isPlayerA){
       btnPosition[i].setText("O");
       isPlayerA = false;
       displayPlayer.setText("Player A");
   }
   else{
       btnPosition[i].setText("X");
       isPlayerA = true;
       displayPlayer.setText("Player B");
   }
   btnPosition[i].setDisable(true);
   findWinner();
}

public void findWinner(){
    checkRows();
    checkColumns();
    checkDiagonals();
    if(hasWinner){
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        btnPosition[i].setDisable(true);
    }
    if(winningChar == 'O'){
        displayPlayer.setText("Player A has WON!");
    }
        else{
        displayPlayer.setText("Player B has WON!");
    }
  }
    else{ // i added this else to find out if i could make it into a tie... 
          //but after someone clicks one button it says its a tie but the game keeps playing
      displayPlayer.setText("It's a Tie!");
   }
}
```

Here is one of my methods for checkRows() if it makes a difference:

```
    public void checkRows(){
    if(btnPosition[0].getText().equals(btnPosition[1].getText())
            && btnPosition[1].getText().equals(btnPosition[2].getText())
            && btnPosition[2].getText().equals(btnPosition[3].getText())
            && !btnPosition[3].getText().isEmpty()){
            hasWinner = true;
            setWinner();
    }
    else  if(btnPosition[3].getText().equals(btnPosition[4].getText())
            && btnPosition[4].getText().equals(btnPosition[5].getText())
            && btnPosition[5].getText().equals(btnPosition[6].getText())
            && !btnPosition[6].getText().isEmpty()){
            hasWinner = true;
            setWinner();
    }
```

etc... So can anyone help into finding a way to have my game make it say It's a Tie at the end if no one wins and all 16 squares are filled? Im looking for the most simplest solution. oh and if your wondering whats in setWinner() it's the following:

```
          public void setWinner(){
    if(!isPlayerA){
        winningChar = 'O';
    }
    else{
        winningChar = 'X';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` and `else if` in `checkRows()` are doing the same thing.

Comment: Please read tags before using them. `Tie` refers to Perl.

Comment: Just check if all buttons are disabled.

Comment: yeah it's just to check if the winningchar within each of those buttons then hasWinner becomes true and i disable the buttons. @sillyfly where would i put the code to disable all the buttons. i tried that by taking my for loop and pasting it in the else of findWinner() but it didn't work

Comment: why dont you just check for `if(!hasWinner){//Do your tie stuff} else { if(!isPlayerA){...`?